# Upgrading Helmet to v4.5.0 and needing equivalent type to IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives

Tags: types, helmet.js

Just amending the dependencies used in a NodeJS/ Typescript application and have hit a snag with the Helmet change from version "3.23.2" to “4.5.0”.

I've removed the dependency "@types/helmet": "0.0.47" from the package.json file.

A compilation results in the following semantic errors:

```
src/loaders/security.ts(2,18): error TS2305: Module '"helmet"' has no exported member 'IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives'.
src/options.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"helmet"' has no exported member 'IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives'.
```

options.ts includes:

```
import { IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives } from 'helmet';

export interface Options {
  redirectUrl: string;
  mountPath: string;
  serviceName?: string;
  views?: string | string[];
  csp?: IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives;
  i18n?: I18nOptions;
}
```

security.ts is defined as:

```
import { Application } from 'express';
import helmet, { IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives } from 'helmet';
import logger from '../lib/logger';

const configureSecurity = (app: Application, csp: IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives | undefined): void => {
  logger.info('Configuring Security using Helmet');
  const defaultSrc = (csp && csp.defaultSrc) || [];
  const styleSrc = (csp && csp.styleSrc) || [];
  const scriptSrc = (csp && csp.scriptSrc) || [];
  app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: [...defaultSrc, "'self'"],
        styleSrc: [...styleSrc, "'self'"],
        scriptSrc: [
          ...scriptSrc,
          "'self'",
          "'sha256-+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'",
          "'sha256-+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'",
        ],
      },
    },
  }));
};

export default configureSecurity;
```

I can't work out what to use instead of `IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives` for the csp type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of Helmet here.

Helmet v3 did not have official TypeScript definitions and Helmet v4 does. In short, you're seeing this problem because the community-made types for Helmet v3 don't map cleanly to the official types in Helmet v4.

You're looking for an alternative to `IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives`. Here's [a snippet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/blob/62b2c64fe3341a554ba76cdc4a105207a90de19b/middlewares/content-security-policy/index.ts#L12-L16) from Helmet's official type definitions for the Content Security Policy module:

```js
export interface ContentSecurityPolicyOptions {
  directives?: Record<
    string,
    | Iterable<ContentSecurityPolicyDirectiveValue>
    | typeof dangerouslyDisableDefaultSrc
  >;
  reportOnly?: boolean;
}
```

The `directives` key of `ContentSecurityPolicyOptions` is the "reincarnation" of the old `IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives`.

I see two options:

1. Define the type yourself, and then use it. For example:

   ```js
   type CspDirectiveValue =
     | string
     | ((req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => string);

   type CspDirectives = Record<string, Iterable<CspDirectiveValue>>;
   ```

   You can then use `CspDirectives` in place of the old `IHelmetContentSecurityPolicyDirectives` type.
2. Rework your code a bit.

   You could update the `Options` interface to take *all* of Helmet's options:

   ```js
   import helmet from 'helmet';

   export interface Options {
     // ...
     helmetOptions: Parameters<typeof helmet>[0];
     // ...
   }
   ```

   You can then use it in `configureSecurity`:

   ```js
   const configureSecurity = (app: Application, helmetOptions: Parameters<typeof helmet>[0]): void => {
     // ...
     app.use(helmetOptions);
   };
   ```

   Your actual code might vary a bit.